# Having issues with javascript client side validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am having problem with my code. I have to cancel the form before submitting if there is an error. I have to add the e.preventDefault() somewhere in the code in order to stop submitting only if there is an error. Here is my code

HTML

```
    <form id="c-form" method="post" action="users.php">
        <div class="c-form-input-main-container">
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-firstname"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-lastname"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="email">Email <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-email"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="country">Country <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <select id="country" name="country" class="c-form-data">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="us">United States</option>
                    <option value="au">Australia</option>
                </select>
                <small id="c-error-message-country"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="phone">Phone <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-phone"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="password">Password <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-password"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password <span class="c-required-input">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="c-form-data">
                <small id="c-error-message-cpassword"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container c-form-radio-container">
                <div><label for="male" class="c-radio"></div>
                <label for="male" class="c-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="c-radio-input" id="male">
                    <div class="c-radio-button"></div>
                    Male
                </label>
                <label for="female" class="c-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="c-radio-input" id="female">
                    <div class="c-radio-button"></div>
                    Female
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container">
                <label for="message">Your Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                <small id="c-error-message-message"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container c-form-input-container-terms">
                <label for="terms" class="c-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="c-checkbox-input" value="termsAccepted" id="terms">
                    <div class="c-checkbox-button"></div>
                    <span class="c-terms-link">Agree To Our<a href="#" target="_blank"> Terms & Conditions</a></span>
                </label>
                <small id="c-error-message-terms"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="c-form-input-container c-form-submit-container">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript Code

regForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
let firstname = document.querySelector("#firstname");
let lastname = document.querySelector("#lastname");
let email = document.querySelector("#email");
let country = document.querySelector("#country");
let phone = document.querySelector("#phone");
let password = document.querySelector("#password");
let cpassword = document.querySelector("#cpassword");

let nameError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-firstname");
let lastnameError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-lastname");
let mailError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-email");
let countryError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-country");
let phoneError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-phone");
let passwordError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-password");
let cpasswordError = document.querySelector("#c-error-message-cpassword");

let errorMesages = document.querySelectorAll(".c-form-input-container small");

errorMesages.forEach((error) => {
    error.innerText = "";
    error.style.color = "red";
});



if (firstname.value == "") {
    nameError.innerText = "Firstname Required";
}
if (lastname.value == "") {
    lastnameError.innerText = "Lastname Required";
}
if (email.value == "") {
    mailError.innerText = "Email Required";
}
if (country.value == "") {
    countryError.innerText = "Country Required";
}
if (phone.value == "") {
    phoneError.innerText = "Phone Required";
}
if (password.value == "") {
    passwordError.innerText = "Password Required";
}
if (cpassword.value !== password.value) {
    cpasswordError.innerText = "Passwords Do Not Match";
}
```

});

Comment: quick and dirty: `if (Array.from(errorMesages).some(e => e.innerText != "")) e.preventDefault();`

Comment: try it but nothing

Comment: Did you a) put my line at the end of the function b) remove your `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/v8uxyjqs/